# Topological quotients of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by subspaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Then, let $X_A$ denote $X/R$, where:

$$R = \{ (x,y) : x = y  \text{ or } (x,y) \in A \times A\}$$

i.e. we collapse $A$ to a point. I will call $X_A$ the quotient of $X$ by $A$.

**Conjecture**: Let $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $K \subseteq X$ be compact and path-connected with path-connected complement. Then, $X_K$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

You may note that, for the case $n=2$, this is similar to the Jordan curve theorem, which I don't want to assume.

---

I think that this is true, but it's quite difficult to construct the required homeomorphism; I think I would need to brush up my analysis first. Equally, if it's not true, I don't have the imagination to guess what the counterexample looks like. I've only proved a basic lemma:

**Lemma**: Let $Y,Z$ be topological spaces. Let $U_n \subseteq Y$ be an increasing family of open sets such that $\bigcup_n U_n = Y$ and for each $n$, there exists $f_n$ such that

- $f_n : U_n \to Z$ is a homeomorphism onto its image
- $f_n \restriction_{U_k}=f_k$ for any $k \le n$
- $\bigcup_n f_n(U_n) = Z$

Then, $Y \cong Z$.

Of course, this is nothing astonishing; the proof is just to take the union of all the homeomorphisms, so to speak. But it should simplify the proof of the conjecture.

Comment: This is already false when $n=2$ (take $A$ which is the [Comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space)). Nevertheless, if $A$ is "cell-like" and $n=2$, then $R^2/A$ is homeomorphic to $R^2$ (this is a consequence of a Moore's Theorem). Things go really wrong in dimension 3: One can find some $A\subset R^3$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ such that $R^3/A$ is not a manifold (Bing's example).  Specifically, take $A$ which has non-simply connected complement.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! That's a very comprehensive answer. The comb is a nice space to be aware of. I should have only stated it for $n=2$ in hindsight; it's not too surprising that stuff goes wrong for $n>2$. For $n=2$, I wanted to extend it to a proof of the Jordan curve theorem. Suppose that $A \cong S^1$ (I presume $S^1$ is cell-like) has the property above. Then, I think the homeomorphism would imply that $S^1$ is contractible. Does that sound about right? Moore's theorem looks more difficult to prove than JCT, so this is just academic now.

Comment: No, the circle is not cell-like.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By cell-like, do you mean homeomorphic to a $k$-cell for $k \le 2$?

Comment: No, but this provides some examples. What I wrote in my first comment was not quite right, I will post a proper answer with details in a little while. But if you are trying to prove the JCT using this staff, it's a wrong thing to do since all the results about cell-like subsets are much harder than the JCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer clarifying and correcting my earlier comment.

1. For each $n\ge 3$, there exists a subset $A\subset R^n$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ (hence, path-connected with connected complement) such that $Q=R^n/A$ is not a topological manifold, hence, is not homeomorphic to $R^n$. The example is essentially due to Bing: Take a (wild) arc $A$ embedded in $R^n$ such that $R^n\setminus A$ is not simply-connected. Then $Q$ is simply-connected but removing a point from $Q$ (namely, the projection of $A$) makes it non-simply-connected. Hence, $Q$ cannot be a topological manifold.
2. Suppose that $A\subset R^2$ is a compact such that its complement is simply-connected (which follows from your assumptions but is strictly weaker). Then $R^2/A$ is homeomorphic to $R^3$.

This is an application of several nontrivial results which will also require several definitions.

(a) A compact metrizable space is said to be **cell-like** if for some (equivalently, every) embedding $i$ of $A$ in the Hilbert cube $H$ has the property that for every neighborhood $U$ of $i(A)$ in $H$, the inclusion $i(A)\to U$ is null-homotopic. For instance, a closed ball is cell-like but the circle is not.

This definition is a bit hard to digest. But there is a *sufficient condition* for $A$ to be cell-like:

(b) A compact subset $A\subset R^k$ is said to be **cellular** if there is a decreasing sequence of  neighborhoods $U_j$ of $A$ in $R^k$ such that:

(i) Each $U_j$ is homeomorphic to $R^k$.

(ii) $\bigcap_{j} U_j=A$.

As it turns out, if $A\subset R^k$ is compact and $R^k\setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $R^k$, then $A$ is cellular. This theorem is due to M.Brown:

*Brown, Morton*, [**The monotone union of open $n$-cells is an open $n$-cell**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2034881), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 12, 812-814 (1961). [ZBL0103.39305](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0103.39305).

In particular, if $A\subset R^2$ is a compact with simply-connected complement, then $A$ is cellular.

Lastly, R.Moore proved in

*Moore, R. L.*, [**Concerning upper semi-continuous collections of continua.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1989234), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 27, 416-428 (1925). [ZBL51.0464.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:51.0464.03).

that if $A\subset R^2$ is cell-like then $R^2/A$ is homeomorphic to $R^2$ (in fact, he proves much more but you do not need this).

See also

*Edwards, Robert D.*, The topology of manifolds and cell-like maps, Proc. int. Congr. Math., Helsinki 1978, Vol. 1, 111-127 (1980). [ZBL0428.57004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0428.57004).

for more details and references.

Comment: Fascinating. Thank you. When I was working on the question, I imagined that, on an intuitive level, if a space is homeomorphic to its own quotient by a subspace, then the subspace must be trivial in some sense. Is there any truth to this intuition - would cell-like/cellular spaces be considered quite "nice"? Both (a),(b) do seem fairly restrictive.